# How to go trough JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I have this output from ajax call:

```
"total":"3",
"data":[{   "id":"4242",
            "title":"Yeah Lets Go!",
            "created":"1274700584",
            "created_formated":"2010-07-24 13:19:24",
            "path":"http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah"
        }]
```

So there is three that kind of items in that array and I would need to go that through and print actual html out of it. So on page it would be:

> Yeah Lets Go! (which is a link to http:www.domain.com/yeah)
>      Created: 2010-07-24 13:19:24

I'm clueles with this one.

Edit 1:
Also atm I get that raw output after clicking link. How can I get it to show on page load? Or it does that ajax call when I click link atm.

Edit 2:
I got it to output everything at once. But still I have a prolem with putting it actual html. The output atm is:

```
"total":"3",
"data":[{
            "id":"4242",
            "title":"Yeah Lets Go!",
            "created":"1274700584",
            "created_formated":"2010-07-24 13:19:24",
            "path":"http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah"
        }
        {
            "id":"4242",
            "title":"Yeah Lets Go!222",
            "created":"1274700584",
            "created_formated":"2010-07-24 13:19:24",
            "path":"http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah222"
        }
        {
            "id":"4242",
            "title":"Yeah Lets Go!333",
            "created":"1274700584",
            "created_formated":"2010-07-24 13:19:24",
            "path":"http:\/\/domain.com\/yeah333"
        }
]}
```

I would like to get that into list with title and link and creation day.

Edit 3 after [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652299/1111767) from [Luca Matteis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50394/luca-matteis):
Hmm, now im even more confused.

That JSON string comes out of this:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
        var item_id = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
        $.get(base_url+'/ajax/get_itema/'+item_id+'/0/3/true', 
                null, 
                function(data, status, xhr) {
                    $('#contentCell').html(data);
                }
        );
```

So I would need to do for that is something like:

```
var html = eval(data);
```

and then I would do what Luca Matteis [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652299/1111767)?

Comment: You should probaly add `dataType: "json"` option to the `jQuery.ajax` to convert the data returned from the server to the object.

Answer (score 2):

First off, that's a JSON string, you need to un-serialize the string into a real JavaScript object (look at [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) for this).

Once you have the native JavaScript data, something like this should work:

```
var html = '';
for(var i=0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
    html += '<a href="'+obj.data[i].path+'">'+obj.data[i].title+'</a><br>';
    html += 'Created: '+ obj.data[i].created;

}
```

Comment: It's serialized as JSON and needs to be de-serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, now im even more confused.

That JSON string comes out of this:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
var item_id = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
$.get(base_url+'/ajax/get_itema/'+item_id+'/0/3/true', null, function(data, status, xhr) {
$('#contentCell').html(data);
});
```

So I would need to do for that is something like:

```
var html = eval(data);
```

and then I would do what Luca Matteis suggest?